# Trying to parse a JSON file but it seems the format is different or something is wrong with the JSON file

Tags: json, file, parsing

Hi I'm trying to parse any of the files from the link underneath. I've tried reaching out to the owner of the data dumps, but nothing works in trying to parse the files as proper JSON files. No program we use (Power BI, Jupyter, Excel) anything really, wants to recognise the files as JSON and we can't figure out why this might be. I was wondering if anyone could help figuring out what the issue is here as this dataset is very interesting to me and my co-students. I hope I'm using the word 'parsing' correctly.

The link to the data dumps is linked underneath:

https://files.pushshift.io/reddit/comments/

Answer (score 0):

The file I downloaded (I just tried one at random) was handled just fine by [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), my preferred command-line tool for processing JSON files.

`jq` accepts an input consisting of a sequence of JSON objects, which is what I found when I decompressed the test file. This format is commonly known as JSON lines, and many tools can handle it. [The Wikipedia article on JSON streaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming) contains more information and a (possibly outdated) list of tools.

If your tools aren't capable of handling more than one JSON object in an input, you could turn the files into something which you can handle by adding a comma to the end of every line except the last one (since each JSON object is a single line) and then surrounding the whole input inside a pair of brackets to turn the sequence into a JSON list. Since JSON does not actually care about newlines, it would be sufficient to add a line containing `[` at the beginning and a line containing `]` at the end. I don't know what command-line tools you have available and are comfortable with, but the task shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Hi, thanks, we are just not very experienced with JSON in general. Can you give a clue as to how you would turn the file into a multiple JSON object file, so simpler programs can use it?

Comment: @Rasrp: that hint is in the answer but you might be better off finding a more capable tool, or reading the documentation for the tool you're using.